# Swagger: How to document REST imput param, when dtois implicitly coverted to entity?

Tags: java, swagger, jersey-2.0

There isa problem, when we use Jersey2 resource with implicitly dto usage.

**Example:**

```
@POST
@ApiOperation(value = "Create pet", response = PetDTO.class)
public Pet create(Pet pet) throws IOException {
    return this.petService.save(pet);
}
```

In this example we implicitly get petDto as param, and than map it to entity.

The question is, is the way to how to configure swagger to document PetDTO as api param, not Pet?

Answer (score 0):

It can be done next way:

```
@POST
@ApiOperation(value = "Create pet", response = PetDTO.class)
@ApiImplicitParams({
        @ApiImplicitParam(name = "Pet dto",
        value = "pet", required = true,
        dataType = "com.example.PetDTO", paramType = "body")
})

public Pet create(@ApiParam(hidden = true) Pet pet) throws IOException {
}
```