# How to make SpringFox Swagger render a string parameter as another model type?

Tags: java, swagger, springfox

How can I make Swagger document a String resource parameter as a full class type?

I.e. I have this resource declaration:

```
@PatchMapping(path="/{id}")
public ApiResponse<MyObject> patch(@PathVariable String id, @RequestBody String myObjText) {
```

I want `myObjText` to be documented as having a model of type `MyObject` while still be able to get the raw JSON text in the method body (that's because I later want to call `readerForUpdating()` over a Jackson `objectMapper`).

`@ApiParam` seems to be ignored for `@RequestBody` parameters, and none of `@ApiModel*` annotations are allowed there.

I'm using `springfox` since these are Spring Rest resources.

Comment: I think this cant be done. If the request body is String type any string (not just json strings) will be accepted by the API. Spring has a way of customizing default ObjectMapper which you may try. Refer here https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-spring-mvc.html#howto-customize-the-jackson-objectmapper

Comment: @Archit, I'm not worried about validation or further data processing, I just want the _documentation_ to be more descriptive than providing a generic `String` type about my parameter format

Comment: Ok. Then maybe you are handling String validation explicitly in controller code or else client can invoke API with any random payload.

Comment: @watery I'm trying to achieve the same. Have you found a solution?

Comment: @Marc I ended up using [Alexander Terekhov's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51099821/3127111) - see further GitHub issue.

Answer (score 3):

Try to override String param as `@ApiParam(hidden = true)` and add
new param for your object:

```
@ApiImplicitParams({
        @ApiImplicitParam(name = "My obj text",
        value = "myObjText", required = true,
        dataType = "com.example.MyObject", paramType = "body")
})
```

Like it is implemented here:
[How to document implicitly dto usage, when we use entity class as api param?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41481588/how-to-document-implicitly-dto-usage-when-we-use-entity-class-as-api-param/41543595#41543595)

Comment: This is not working (I'm wondering if this could be a Springfox issue).

Comment: It seems this works when the `dataType` parameter has a non package qualified value, i.e. `dataType="MyObject"` (see SpringFox [issue 2523](https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/2523)).

Comment: Maybe, I have tested it only with Jersey.

Answer (score 2):

In my case two changes needed to be made:

1) Added `@ImplicitParams` (type name is not qualified with package name)

```
@ApiImplicitParams({
    @ApiImplicitParam(name = "requestBody", required = true,
        dataType = "MyObject", paramType = "body")
})
```

2) Registered implicit model type (especially when response type is `ResponseEntity(Void.class)`

```
@Configuration
public class SwaggerConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private TypeResolver typeResolver;

    @Bean
    public Docket docket() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
            .additionalModels(typeResolver.resolve(MyObject.class));
    }

}
```