# Springfox creates 'ref' type instead of java.io.File object in Swagger 2.0 JSON Definition

Tags: java, rest, swagger, java-io, springfox

I am attempting to describe a REST POST endpoint that takes two `java.io.File` objects as part of a `multipart/form-data` payload using Java annotations from Swagger. Upon intitial research, I found that this could be accomplished by specifying implicit parameters with the following properties set (namely `type`, `dataType`, and `paramType`)

```
    @ApiImplicitParams({
        @ApiImplicitParam(
                name="controlFile",
                value="Control file to be used in the comparison.",
                required=true,
                type="file",
                paramType="form",
                dataType="java.io.File"),
        @ApiImplicitParam(
                name="testFile",
                value="Test file to be used in the comparison.",
                required=true,
                type="file",
                paramType="form",
                dataType="java.io.File")
    })
    @PostMapping(
            consumes=MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA,
            produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON
    )
    public ResponseEntity<Void> submitComparisonRequest(
            final UriComponentsBuilder uriBuilder,
            @Context final HttpServletRequest request) {

        try {
            final FileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
            final ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
            final FileItemIterator items = upload.getItemIterator(request);

            final FileItemStream control = items.next();
            final FileItemStream test = items.next();
```

In the part of the JSON contract that describes these parameters, everything looks correct **EXCEPT** the `type` field value is `ref` instead of the excepected `java.io.File`.

```
"parameters": [
    {
        "name": "controlFile",
        "in": "formData",
        "description": "Control file to be used in the comparison.",
        "required": true,
        "type": "ref"
    },
    {
        "name": "testFile",
        "in": "formData",
        "description": "Test file to be used in the comparison.",
        "required": true,
        "type": "ref"
    }
],
```

I have tried several different combinations of using `dataType` vs `dataTypeClass` and other strategies from in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51098932/2096689) SO question, but I have not been able to get the JSON contract generated correctly.

For reference, I am using Springfox 2.9.2 and SpringMVC 5.2.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After digging around some more, I was able to find out that `dataType` for `@ApiImplicitParam` parameters should not be the fully qualified path to the `java.io.File` object, it should be specified as `__file`.

[Here](https://springfox.github.io/springfox/docs/current) is a link to the SpringFox documentation. (Listed under 6.5 Overriding property datatypes)